# Browser compatibility issue when using ::before css selector on optgroup tag

Tags: css

The following code gets the desired results only on Chrome:

HTML:

```
<select multiple style="width:500px">
  <optgroup class="outg" label="Swedish Cars">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

CSS:

```
.outg::before {
  content: "";
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 7px 0 7px 7px;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #656565;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 3px;
  width: 10px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2ny35p94/3/

---

**Chrome 58 - both triangle and label are displayed:**
[image]

**Firefox 53 - only the triangle is displayed:**
[image]

**IE 11 - only the label is displayed:**
[image]

---

Any suggestion on how to make it cross browser compatible?

Comment: `optgroup` support is dodgy before you even start throwing CSS at it. If you want browser support, limit yourself to `option` elements and background images/ASCII art/non-breaking spaces/`disabled` to achieve something that will behave and look similar; or go for a custom solution that uses JavaScript to provide the functionality and formatting abilities desired.

Comment: I would not use only ::before for a stable solution to this...

Answer (score 1):

You can't show both because you are overriding the default `::before`, that's exactly what the browser does. Chrome seems to apply it but it's not on the standard specification. So in this case, Firefox and IE are working as expected.

The `<optgroup>` tag is styling by the browser as this:

```
optgroup[label]::before {
     content: attr(label);
}
```

If you override the `content` property, there's nothing you can do.

My suggestion is to remove the `content` property on your code, but you will have to fix another related issues. See the screenshot:

[image: firefox screenshot]

See it working:

https://jsfiddle.net/2ny35p94/4/

Comment: Also refer this post https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=219417

Comment: Good **historical** reference @JonesJoseph , but I agree with the comments that's not a bug. There are tons of options before overriding that style.

Comment: That should at least make it possible to insert some unicode character like a right-pointing black triangle before the attribute content, `content: "\25B6" attr(label);` https://jsfiddle.net/2ny35p94/5/ (I added `font-style:normal` there, because in italic a triangle character looks rather weird ...)

Comment: Removing the 'content' property will "fix" the problem on Firefox, but will cause the triangle to disappear on Chrome and IE.